# What copyright issues could arise if I write a book based on one of my articles?

Tags: publications, copyright

If I publish a 187 pages article extracted from a 244 (yet unpublished) page book, do I have the future right to publish this book without consent from the article copyright holder?

What if the book would become much longer than the 244 pages mentioned above?

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Comment: A **187 page article‽**

Comment: @BenjaminMakoHill: There are journals which publish 200 pages and even longer articles

Comment: @porton: There are predatory journals that publish anything that comes with a check for USD$500. :) What field or journal are you thinking of?

Answer (score 3):

**You always need consent from the copyright holder.** If you have published in an [libre open access](http://www.sparc.arl.org/resource/gratis-and-libre-open-access) journal (e.g., [CC BY](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) licensed), you probably have it. Very often, copyright agreements people sign with journals (at least in the social sciences) allow authors to republish article content in books and dissertations. If this is what your agreements say, you already have that consent. Sometimes, you will need to ask for consent but, in my field at least, it is usually given.

Generally speaking, book publisher are also OK publishing books that contain work previously published in articles. That said, I think your example of trying to turn a 187 page article into a 244 page book is unlikely to fly.

For one, acquisition editors at scholarly publishers are fundamentally interested in selling books. One thing they think about is whether or not there is a market for the book. If a book proposal describes work that is already published in journals, editors will want to see what the book adds on top of the existing published work. It's going to be hard to show that in the example above where 77% of the book is available verbatim elsewhere.

Book editors (like judges in copyright cases) are not robots. Intention and acting in good faith matters. If it looks like you are trying to game the system to score extra publications or extra book income without much extra work, people will notice and do what they can to stop you. Since, editors have a lot of power, that will often be quite a lot.

Comment: _If you have published in an open access journal, you already have it_ - not necessarily. Some OA journals (especially predatory ones) _do_ require copyright transfer, and they may retain some rights (like exclusive publication).

Comment: Good point. I've edited the sentence to make it clear that I was referring to [libre open access](http://www.sparc.arl.org/resource/gratis-and-libre-open-access) and made the statement more tentative.